# Free hand painting and erasing using UIBezierPath and CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have been trying so much but have no solution find out yet. I have to implement the painting and erasing on iOS so I successfully implemented the painting logic using `UIBezierPath`. The problem is that for erasing, I implemented the same logic as for painting by using `kCGBlendModeClear` but the problem is that I cant redraw on the erased area and this is because in each pass in drawRect i have to stroke both the painting and erasing paths. So is there anyway that we can subtract erasing path from drawing path to get the resultant path and then stroke it. I am very new to Core Graphics and looking forward for your reply and comments. Or any other logic to implement the same. I can't use eraser as background color because my background is textured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to stroke the path every time, in fact doing so is a huge performance hit.  I guarantee if you try it on an iPad 3 you will be met with a nearly unresponsive screen after a few strokes.  You only need to add and stroke the path once.  After that, it will be stored as pixel data.  So don't keep track of your strokes, just add them, stroke them, and get rid of them.  Also look into using a CGLayer (you can draw to that outside the main loop, and only render it to your rect in the main loop so it saves lots of time).

These are the steps that I use, and I am doing the exact same thing (I use a CGPath instead of UIBezierPath, but the idea is the same):

1) In touches began, store the touch point and set the context to either erase or draw, depending on what the user has selected.

2) In touches moved, if the point is a certain arbitrary distance away from the last point, then move to the last point (`CGContextMoveToPoint`) and draw a line to the new point (`CGContextAddLineToPoint`) in my `CGLayer`.  Calculate the rectangle that was changed (i.e. contains the two points) and call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` with that rectangle.

3) In drawRect render the `CGLayer` into the current window context ( `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` ).

On an iPad 3 (the one that everyone has the most trouble with due to its enormous pixel count) this process takes between 0.05 ms and 0.15ms per render (depending on how fast you swipe).  There is one caveat though, if you don't take the proper precautions, the entire frame rectangle will be redrawn even if you only use `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`  My hacky way to combat this (thanks to the dev forums) is described in my self answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11199648/1155387),  Otherwise, if your view takes a long time to draw the entire frame (mine took an unacceptable 150 ms) you will get a short stutter under certain conditions while the view buffer gets recreated.

*EDIT* With the new info from your comments, it seems that the answer to this question will benefit you -> [Use a CoreGraphic Stroke as Alpha Mask in iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208579/use-a-coregraphic-stroke-as-alpha-mask-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Hi Borrrden, thanks for your response but what do you mean by "set the context to either erase or draw" in your very first point

Comment: Let me elobarate my problem more, i have two images, wherever user brushes the paint the top image will be vanished through that stroke and the bottom image will be shown at this place and whenever a eraser is stroked top image will be back at this place and the bottom image which were shown at this place would be vanished

Comment: Actually it could be very simple if there is a way to change the alpha value of the pixels of the top image that lies under the stroke of CGPath. But I am very much new to CoreGraphics so I did not find a way to do that

Comment: This information would have been valuable in your original question.  In that case, I think you should look into masking:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208579/use-a-coregraphic-stroke-as-alpha-mask-in-iphone-app

Comment: Thanks a lot Borrrden your answers really helped me.

Comment: Hi Borrrden, what I implemented is that in my touches began i am reallocating my path and in touchesmoved method, I am continously creating a mask image by stroking path, but the performance is really slow? any suggestion to overcome this problem.

Comment: I am answering the same question for someone else as well ><.  Don't store paths!  The longer your path is the longer it will take to stroke it.  You need to draw directly into your image context (via CGContext commands).  Watch the WWDC 2012 session iOS Performance: Graphics, this problem gets addressed.

Comment: Borrden, I checked my code by simply drawing the mask image, it is fast, it masking that is taking time, I am creating mask like that in my touchesmoved method. http://pastebin.com/HrWSyiRr

Comment: If it is CGImageCreateWithMask that is causing the slowdown, then I'm afraid you will have to give up this method, or make your images smaller.  What does Instruments say?

Comment: Hello @borrrden, I have a issue with erase, please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033228/eraser-the-drawing-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

Hai here is the code for making painting, erasing, undo, redo, saving as picture. you can check sample code and implement this on your project.
[Here](https://github.com/sumanthk2006/Smooth-Line-View-1)

Comment: Thanks Sumanth for your quick response, I looked at this code, but this is not the solution of my problem as its eraser is clearing the background texture image as well, i needed something that actually intersect my drawing strokes path and erasing strokes path to have a resultant path that I can stroke to preserve my background image.